# CommunicationException in WCF Service

Tags: wcf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

My problem is that AddExcursionAsync doesn't work, it shows CommunicationException.
In Console application this code works well. But in Silverlight it makes error. Functions 
AddListOgTourNumbersAsync and GetListOfTourNumberAsync work correctly. Where I did the error?

Code:

```
private AdminServiceClient client;
    public AddExcursionDialog()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DurationElement.Value = new DateTime();
        client = new AdminServiceClient();
        client.GetListOfTourNumberCompleted += new EventHandler<GetListOfTourNumberCompletedEventArgs>(GetListOfTourNumber);
        client.AddListOgTourNumbersCompleted += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(AddListOfTourNumbers);
        client.AddExcursionCompleted += new EventHandler<AsyncCompletedEventArgs>(AddExcursion);
    }
    private void OKButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        excursion = new Excursion();
        excursion.Name = NameText.Text;
        excursion.Cost = Convert.ToDouble(CostText.Text);
        excursion.Place = PlaceText.Text;
        excursion.Duration= (DateTime)DurationElement.Value;
        excursion.Agency_id = tour_names[AgencyCB.SelectedValue.ToString()];
        excursion.MaxPpl = Convert.ToInt32(MaxPplText.Text);
        client.GetListOfTourNumberAsync();
        client.AddExcursionAsync(excursion);
        client.AddListOgTourNumbersAsync(tour_id, excursion.NumberOfList);
        this.DialogResult = true;
    }
```

Comment: You Must Add Service Contract In Wcf Services

Answer (score 0):

I have also battled with `CommunicationException(s)`. At that point, I believe the network were experiencing regular problems.

In my scenario I had to stabilise this call with a **retry** algorithm.

I'm not saying you should do this all the time, but use it to test.

In this code, the exception is allowed to be thrown if the 3rd attempt fails.

```
    string[] Images64;

    try { /* 1st try */
        Images64 = _VideoClient.GetImagesStr(ImagePaths[0], ImagePaths[1], LFrame, RFrame);
    }
    catch (CommunicationException) {

        try { /* 2nd try */
            Images64 = _VideoClient.GetImagesStr(ImagePaths[0], ImagePaths[1], LFrame, RFrame);
        }
        catch (CommunicationException) {

            try { /* 3rd try */
                Images64 = _VideoClient.GetImagesStr(ImagePaths[0], ImagePaths[1], LFrame, RFrame);
            }
            catch (CommunicationException) {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```